# How to add change directory and git pull to this crontab line?

Tags: bash, shell-script, cron

I have this directory structure:

```
/var/sync/
├── sync_bi
├── sync_pfizer
└── sync_sandbox
```

I have a few files running by the following cronjob:

```
10 */12 * * * find /var/sync/ -name 'Replicator.php' -execdir php {} \; ; find /var/sync/ -name 'sync.php' -execdir php {} \;
```

I am asking which is the proper way to add the commands `cd /var/sync/sync_*` and `git pull` as for example taking the directories above as example I should:

```
cd /var/sync/sync_bi && git pull and after git pull ends then find /var/sync/ -name 'Replicator.php' -execdir php {} \; ; find /var/sync/ -name 'sync.php' -execdir php {} \;
cd /var/sync/sync_pfizer && git pull ... the same as line above
cd /var/sync/sync_sandbox && git pull ... the same as line above
```

Can any help me to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You should put all your commands in a shell script, make it executable and reference it in your cronjob. E.g.:

```
10 */12 * * * /home/myuser/scripts/myscript.sh
```

where `myscript.sh` is the file containing all your commands.

As a side note:

The `&&` operator means that the command on the right side only gets executed if the command on the left side ran successfully (`exit 0`)